# MSSQL ODBC Connection in Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc

I have vb project installed in linux wine. I want to create odbc connection to mssql database. How do I connect to MSSQl SERVER. any one can help me.. plz

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has an [ODBC Linux driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160) that provides native connectivity from Linux to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I tried this but not working. installation error has occurred.

Comment: I have run the install.sh but not anything happen. please help me to install it.

Comment: @user2257084 does your linux system meet all of the prerequisites? It's a 64-bit driver. Have you read the README (which wants you to run `./install.sh install`)?

Comment: Verifying processor and operating system  FAILED
Verifying wget is installed ... NOT ATTEMPTED
Verifying tar is installed ... NOT ATTEMPTED
Verifying make is installed ... NOT ATTEMPTED
Downloading unixODBC 2.3.0 DriverManager ... NOT ATTEMPTED
Configuring unixODBC 2.3.0 DriverManager ........................ NOT ATTEMPTED
Building unixODBC 2.3.0 DriverManager ... NOT ATTEMPTED
Errors occurred. See the /tmp/unixODBC.26392.31272.3453/build_dm.log file for more details.

Comment: I've got error `./install.sh: 20: ./install.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: @vladkras I know this is really old, but did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: @MikeS, yes, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I use official docs [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

e.g. one of my Python projects on Ununtu (root user):

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt-get update
apt-get install dialog apt-utils -y
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools msodbcsql17
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc && apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```